Website url works well on browser but breaks when copied on instagram chat
My website urls are working fine on my browser. When I share on instagram chat after copying from the website it work fine and generates a preview correctly. Unfortunately when the preview is clicked it breaks.
Here is an example of the link: https://example.com/product?jbl-tune-720bt
It breaks to this: https://example.com/product
Any idea of what causes this and how to fix this?
The website is running on bootstrap on the front end and php on the backend. I am not using a php framework.

Wild guess -- perhaps Insta is stripping off what it thinks are unused parameters. Try giving the parameter a value, like https://example.com/product?jbl-tune-720bt=0 or similar. That shouldn't break the way your app handles it, and might cause Insta to leave it intact.

@AlexHowansky this works well thanks. Any idea on how I can solve this without adding the extra parameters?

You could add a rewrite rule or change your app's router so that you can use https://example.com/product/jbl-tune-720bt and there are no parameters.
